# Как в WP (WooCommerce) добавить часть кода к другой функции

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть тема. У этой темы есть набор собственных функций, например, файл `woo_options.php`. И пример функции внутри:

```
function icon_markup(){
    global $woocommerce;

    $style = zget_option( 'woo_style', 'wc_options', false, '' );

    if($style == 'style2'){
    ?>
        <span>icon1</span>
    <?php
    }
    else{
    ?>
        <span>icon2</span>
    <?php
    }
}
```

У меня дочерняя тема и нужно, без копирования файла целиком и замены в нем конкретного участка, добавить условие в эту функцию. Могу ли я сделать это, например, в `functions.php`? Или заменить содержимое условия `if($style == 'style2'){...}`? Или только клонирование файла?

Comment: 1. "У меня родительская тема" - может ДОЧЕРНЯЯ?  2. Копирование только вызовет проблемы если функция не проверяется на существование. А если проверяется - достаточно вставить эту функцию в файл функций дочки и изменить. 3 если тема из оф каталога - дай ссылку на неё и скажи в каком файле что посмотреть.

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за уточнение. Да, тема дочерняя. Функцию целиком перенести пробовал, после этого сайт перестает загружаться. Что делать дальше, я примерно представляю, скопировать функцию (и связанные с ней) целиком, переназвать, внести правки и поставить в нужных местах сайта. Просто, хотел уточнить, может есть способ добавить код в существующую функцию. Тема не из оф каталога.

Comment: "Да, тема дочерняя" - тогда исправь вопрос